# Summing certain columns by similar part of its name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to sum columns by already fetched list of unique columns  partly names ?

```
list = ['13-14', '15-16']
```

DataFrame:

```
                 X.13-14        Y.13-14       Z.13-14      X.15-16   ...
id                                                                        
182761           10274.00    6097173.00     5758902.00    3345841.00
```

I.e. I want to create `'13-14'` and `'15-16'`  columns with corresponding sum of (X.13-14,Y.13-14,Z.13-14), then (X.15-16,Y.15-16,Z.15-16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want sum columns by columns names after `.` use lambda function in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[1], axis=1).sum()
print (df1)
             13-14      15-16
id                           
182761  11866349.0  3345841.0
```

Or if need only columns by list:

```
L = ['13-14', '15-16']

df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(f'({"|".join(L)})', expand=False)

df1 = df.sum(level=0, axis=1)[L]
print (df1)
             13-14      15-16
id                           
182761  11866349.0  3345841.0
```

If need add to original:

```
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
        X.13-14    Y.13-14    Z.13-14    X.15-16       13-14      15-16
id                                                                     
182761  10274.0  6097173.0  5758902.0  3345841.0  11866349.0  3345841.0
```